# Android tabs with a logo?

Tags: android

i am trying to figure out if its possible to create tabs in android and have a permanent logo on the left side visible whatever tab the user clicks on.

here is a screen shot example of what i mean

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have make a tab layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RelativeLayout and get the necessary look and feel. I have a similar situation where instead of a tab I have a rollout icon at the home icon level. You could refer to [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)